# How to determine consecutive date records in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a data structure like this:

```
ID     Status     Date
---    ------     ------------
1      I          2013-10-01
1      A          2013-10-02
1      A          2013-10-03
1      I          2013-10-04
1      I          2013-10-05
1      I          2013-10-06
1      A          2013-10-07
1      I          2013-10-08
```

I want to determine how many status `I` are consecutive. In this case 3 (2013-10-04, 05 and 06).

something like this:

```
Status   ID   Total_consecutive
-------  ---  ------------------
A        1    2
I        1    3
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to determine the largest group of consecutive dates, or all groups of consecutive dates?

Comment: are your dates guaranteed to be one day apart?

Comment: hi, @JonLaMarr i am trying to determine if a given ID has more consecutives than a given number.

Comment: @JonLaMarr Example, ID= 1 MaxConsecutive= 3. I need to know if ID = 1 has more than 3 consecutive A's

Comment: @Laurence, no, they are not

Comment: If there is a gap in days, but no other records between them does it still count as consecutive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will give you the correct result:

```
declare @t table
(
    ID INT,    
    [Status] CHAR(1),    
    [Date] DATE
);
insert @t (ID, [Status], [Date])
values (1, 'I', '2013-10-01'),
(1, 'A', '2013-10-02'),
(1, 'A', '2013-10-03'),
(1, 'I', '2013-10-04'),
(1, 'I', '2013-10-05'),
(1, 'I', '2013-10-05'),
(1, 'I', '2013-10-05'),
(1, 'I', '2013-10-06'),
(1, 'A', '2013-10-10')

;with a as
(
select ID, [Status], [Date], 
row_number() over (partition by id order by [Status], [Date])-
row_number() over (partition by id order by [Date], [Status]) rn1

from @t
)
select ID, [Status], min([Date]) Start, max([Date]) [End], 
           count(*) [Total_consecutive] 
from a
group by id, [Status], rn1
having count(*) > 1
```

Result:

```
ID  Status  Start       End         Total_consecutive
1   A       2013-10-02  2013-10-03  2
1   I       2013-10-04  2013-10-06  5
```